# Spring boot - how to use 2 authentication providers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to use 2 authentication providers with Spring Boot using Kotlin:

This method is in a class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport::class)
class SecurityConfiguration(
    ...
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
  @Throws(Exception::class)
  override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
      //super.configure(auth); DON'T DO THIS - for sure...
      val dap = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
      dap.setUserDetailsService(domanUserDetailsService)
      auth.authenticationProvider(LegacyUserDaoAuthenticationProvider(legacyUserService)) . 
      auth.authenticationProvider(dap)
     // Breakpoint here shows that both authentication providers are in the builder
  }
...
}
```

When I run the debugger after the app is running, the `ProviderManager` only has 1 provider.  Somehow, the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is not using the 2 `authenticationProvider`s that have been added to it here. I verified that my `configure` method is being called and that the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` has 2 authentication providers after this method.

Something is happening to step on the setup I've done here (or Spring is not using the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` that I've setup.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if another security is config or autoconfig is being loaded. May you try setting `@Order(1)` in your configuration.